# prevent duplicate invoice no. against particular ID

Tags: sql, duplicates, invoice

I have confusion on how to prevent duplicate `InvoiceNo` against `CompanyId`. I just have prepare an Invoice project that has field like `CompanyId` and `InvNo`. Both do not have Unique Keys because Company ID and InvoiceNo both have to repeated. as per below

```
CompanyID   InvNo
1           1
2           1
1           2
3           1
4           1
1           3
```

Now I want to fire a raiserror on duplicate InvoiceNo against a particular CompanyId. How do I implement this. Important: if i create a unique index then duplicate records will not be allowed and it is important to allow except against particular CompanyId

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a Unique Constraint composed of both CompanyId and InvNo. This will let you create only one InvoiceNo = 1 for CompanyId = 1 and will automatically RaisError if you try to insert a duplicate. It will also let you insert InvoiceNo = 1 for CompanyId = 2 thereby (hopefully) satisfying your requiements

This is how I would do it in SQL Server

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD UNIQUE CONSTRAINT InvoiceIdMustBeUniqePerCompany (CompanyId, InvNo)
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `UNIQUE` in there somewhere?

Comment: Depending on table setup, an alternative would be to define the primary key as a composite key, using `companyid` and `invno`.

Comment: I thought about a PK instead of Constraint, but since he did not post the entire table structure, I did not have enough details to go for that option.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not all that straight forward, but assuming you're asking what I think you're asking, it goes something like this...

You need a cable called NextInvoiceNumber, comprising of CompanyID and NextInvoiceNo. Creating a new Company should create a new NextInvoiceNumber - so perhaps use an insert trigger on your Companies table for that...

Write a function to get the next Invoice id for a specific company, and then incremenent the value in the NextInvoiceNumber table (all inside a common transaction).

So, in pseudo code, something like

```
    function GetNextInvoiceNo(CompanyIDCode){

begin transaction;
result = Select NextInvoiceNo from NextInvoiceNumber where CompanyID = CompanyIDCode;
update NextInvoiceNo set NextInvoiceNo = NextInvoiceNo + 1 where CompanyID = CompanyIDCode;
commit transaction;
return result;
}
```

This function ideally belongs on your database server as a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data it appears that the combination of CompanyID + InvNo is unique.  If that's true you can create a key on those two fields and upon an attempt to insert a duplicate InvNo that has already been used for a particular CompanyID an error would be thrown.

```
create table Invoice
(
CompanyID int,
InvNo int,
Primary Key(CompanyID, InvNo)
)
```